# Add configuration services in program.cs in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

One of configuration's in infrastructure layer

CustomerManagementConfigure.cs

```
public class CustomerManagementConfigure
{
    public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services,string conString)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerApplication, CustomerApplication>();
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();

        services.AddDbContext<DiscountContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(conString));
    }
}
```

program.cs

```
var conString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomerDB");
CustomerManagementConfigure.Configure(services, conString);
ProductManagementConfigure.Configure(services, conString);
```

This way doesn't work in .NET 6.

I have red warning with `IServiceCollection services` instance

Exception:

> The name 'services' does not Exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service collection is available via the `WebApplicationBuilder`'s `Services` property:

```
CustomerManagementConfigure.Configure(builder.Services, conString);
ProductManagementConfigure.Configure(builder.Services, conString);
```